# Ellipsis doesn't work in table cell

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have table where ellipsis should be applied to first cell (first cell should fill the remaining space) but instead table goes outside parent div. How can I make it work?

```css
.wrapper {
  width:200px;
  background: wheat;
}

.el-cell {
  width:99%;
  display: block;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.el {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="el-cell">
        <div class="el">
          <span>first cell should ellipsis aaaaaaa bbbb ccccccc</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="no-wrap">2nd cell</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.el-cell` and `position: absolute` to the `span` with attributes `top: 0` and `left: 0`

```css
.wrapper {
  width:200px;
  background: wheat;
}

.el-cell {
  width:99%;
  position: relative;
}

.el span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="el-cell">
        <div class="el">
          <span>first cell should ellipsis aaaaaaa bbbb ccccccc</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="no-wrap">2nd cell</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `table-layout: fixed`.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` brokes  width 99% - cells fill half of the table.

Comment: Why don't you set 1% width to the other cell? Do you really need so many elements inside each cell? What is the final goal? Keep in mind that 1% of 200px is just too small (2px).

Comment: Because `99%` makes first cell fill whole available space - so second cell is not 1% - it has width of its child.